# passing std::unique_ptr.get() as a parameter to addWidget()

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, stl, smart-pointers

I am trying to pass a `QWidget` pointer argument (`plot2`) to `Qt`'s `addWidget(QWidget * T,...)` function that takes a pointer to a QWidget as its first argument. If I pass the raw pointer `plot2`, I get the two side-by-side panels as expected.

**raw pointer version**

```
    plot1 = new QWidget;
    plot2 = new QWidget;

    gridLayout = new QGridLayout(gridLayoutWidget);
    ...
    gridLayout->addWidget(plot1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
    gridLayout->addWidget(plot2.get(), 1, 2, 1, 1);
```

However, if I use `std::unique_ptr` version of `plot2` and pass the pointer via std::unique_ptr(plot2) as shown in the following snippet, the panel associated with `plot2` goes missing without the compiler making any complaints.

**smart pointer version**

```
    plot1 = new QWidget;
    auto plot2 = std::unique_ptr<QWidget>(new QWidget);

    gridLayout = new QGridLayout(gridLayoutWidget);
    ...
    gridLayout->addWidget(plot1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
    gridLayout->addWidget(plot2.get(), 1, 2, 1, 1); // this panel goes missing
```

I have tried using a `std::shared_ptr` but the result remains the same.

What works of course is if I `release()` the `std::unique_ptr` associated with `plot2` as follows, but then to my understanding I lose the use of the smart pointer version of `plot2` henceforth.

**using std::unique_ptr.release()**

```
    plot1 = new QWidget;
    auto plot2 = std::unique_ptr<QWidget>(new QWidget);

    gridLayout = new QGridLayout(gridLayoutWidget);
    ...
    gridLayout->addWidget(plot1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
    gridLayout->addWidget(plot2.release(), 1, 2, 1, 1);
```

Can you figure out how to get this working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> Adds item at position row, column, spanning rowSpan rows and columnSpan columns, and aligns it according to alignment. If rowSpan and/or columnSpan is -1, then the item will extend to the bottom and/or right edge, respectively. **The layout takes ownership of the item**.

When you add that widget, you no longer own it, so storing in a `std::unique_ptr` then calling `release` is completely reasonable. This is actually preferable to the raw pointer version, as if something throws an exception before you add it to the layout, the memory will be reclaimed automatically.

Comment: Wow! That was a lightening quick response. That makes sense and thanks for the clarification. What if one wants to use `plot2` in a subsequent portion of the code (but within the same scope)?

Comment: You could store a reference to the pointee, but you would be better off restructuring so that you don't need `plot2` after you've added it to the layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
 auto plot2 = std::unique_ptr<QWidget>(new QWidget);
```

Your QWidget* object is deleted after plot2 goes outside the scope. Cause in unique_ptr destructor is something like this

```
~unique_ptr() {delete ptr;}
```

And when the QObject is deleted Qt deletes all gui associated with it.